# Retrieve Value From Database & Replace With Text

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently performing this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM b_tasks WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND GROUP_ID=13 ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This returns:

```
Responsible ID   | Title   | Date Created
2                | Job 1   | 2013/09/20
4                | Job 2   | 2013/09/20
```

The responsible_id represents an actual name in number form.  For example resonsible_id 2 is actually Bob Taylor and responsible_id 4 is Andrew Thompson.  So what I'd like to do is replace the numbers in the table with their name, so where its 2, display Bob Taylor and where its 4 display Andrew Thompson.

I am currently printing these answers using PHP.

```
. $row['RESPONSIBLE_ID'] .
```

Should I be using an IF statement, if responsible_id=2 display Bob and so on?

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

There is a User Table yes, this reads:

Table name: **b_users**

```
ID   | NAME   | LAST_NAME
1    | Andy   | Champ
2    | Bob    | Taylor
3    | Katie  | Gillo
4    | Andrew | Thompson
```

Obviously, ID in this table corresponds with responsible_id in the other table.  Would I be able to join these in the same statement above?

Comment: Are you storing these names anywhere?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question above with the second table with the user details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have a table that you can join to? if not, you can use `CASE`

```
CASE WHEN Responsible_ID = 2 THEN 'Bob Taylor'
     WHEN Responsible_ID = 4 THEN 'Andrew Thompson'
     ELSE Responsible_ID
END AS Responsible_ID
```

---

```
SELECT a.*,
        CONCAT(b.Name, ' ',  b.Last_Name) Fullname
FROM b_tasks a
    INNER JOIN b_users b
        ON a.Responsible_ID = b.ID
WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' AND GROUP_ID=13 
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

and call `$row['Fullname']`

Comment: I've added the user table where the names are stored if that's any use.  Would I be able to join with the original statement?

Comment: That's not pulling anything through, should it not include FROM b_users b as it won't know where to look for the Name and Last Name?

Comment: Yes, that's it.  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE `table` SET `id` = CASE
    WHEN id = 1 THEN 'value1'
    WHEN id = 2 THEN 'value2'
    WHEN id = 3 THEN 'value3'
    ELSE `id`
    END
WHERE id  in (1,2,3)
```